# Дочернии элементы скрыты родительским touch

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
// ------------------- FUNCTION TOUCH SWYPE -------------------- //
  // ------------------------------------------------------------- //

  var accumCordX = 0;
  var absCoordX = 0;
  var startCoordX = 0;
  var moveCoordX = 0;
  var newCordX = 0;

  // ------------------- remember the coordinates of the first touch -------------------- //
  $('.conteiner_slider_1').on('touchstart', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    startCoordX = event.changedTouches[0].pageX;

  });

  // -------------------  -------------------- //
  $('.conteiner_slider_1').on('touchmove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

      moveCoordX = event.changedTouches[0].pageX;
      absCoordX = moveCoordX - startCoordX;
      newCordX = accumCordX + absCoordX;
      offsetLeft = newCordX ;

    $('.content_slider').css({'left':  offsetLeft + "px"});

    markersUpperSlider();
  });

  // ------------------- remember the offset obtained when touchmove -------------------- //
  $('.conteiner_slider_1').on('touchend', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    if( (accumCordX + absCoordX) < -widthOffset ){
      accumCordX = -widthOffset;
      $('.content_slider').css({'left':  accumCordX + "px"});
    }
    else if((accumCordX + absCoordX) > 0){
      accumCordX = 0;
      $('.content_slider').css({'left':  accumCordX + "px"});
    }
    else{
      accumCordX += absCoordX;
    }
  });
```

На родительском блоке весит событие touchstart, touchend, touchmove. Из-за чего дочерние элементы становятся неактивны, в них не выделяется текст и нельзя кликнуть по кнопке. Пробовал stopPropagarion() и удалять у дочерних родительские событие через off() и unbing(). Всё тщетно, помогите

Comment: код покажите????

Comment: надо было пробовать `preventDefault()` а не `stopPropagation()`

Comment: `$(document).bind("touchmove",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        $('.conteiner_slider_1').bind("touchmove",function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
        });`